# Why do I use Laravel collect() instead of simple PHP function?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Recently I have written a code using plain PHP function in Laravel. The code is related to fetching post types and display some meta boxes according to the post type chosen. Post types are hardcoded into the config file.

The problem is that my superior changed that code after reviewing and used Laravel collect() method.

So my question is why should I use that code as the simple code is doing its job very well? Expecting a good reasonable answer.

Please check the code below -

```
<?php
// $post_type => article, news, event
// In config file, metaboxes holdes array of metaboxes whose keys are post types
// $this->config => it is returning the config variables

**Process - I**
$this->metaBoxes = $this->config["metaboxes"][$post_type] ?? [];

foreach ($this->metaBoxes as $key => $value) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $boxes)) {
        ($value)->create($post_type);
    } else {
        unset($this->metaBoxes[$key]);
    }
}

**Process - II**
function getMetaboxes($post_type) {
    $config = $this->config['metaboxes'][$post_type] ?? [];
    return collect($this->metaBoxes)
        ->filter(function ($metabox, $name) use ($config) {
            return array_key_exists($name, $config);
        })
        ->map(function ($metabox) {
            return $metabox;
        })
        ->all();
}
```

Comment: `collect()` is a simple function ... are you asking why to use Collections at all?

Comment: readability, after 6 months or years when visiting the code again and trying to comprehend what's going on, the second one will be easier to read.

Comment: IMHO - the first is clearer - and that is the problem - that is my opinion.  People have their own ideas as to what is better.  Sometimes it can be more standard, sometimes more efficient,  BUT at the end of the day it just comes down to what people prefer.

Comment: also that call to `map` on the collection is not needed, that would the same result as not calling `map`

Comment: One thing I have noticed is that you refer to a variable `$boxes` in the first code, this is not defined anywhere.  In the second code it use the value retrieved in the code.

Comment: @NigelRen I think the two codes are not exactly equivalent, the second one refactor only the getting message part into a function

Comment: you might as well ask this question in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @AnuratChapanond The code looks like a full replacement, after all it uses `array_key_exists` in the filter.

Comment: @NigelRen but I can't find ($value)->create($post_type); anywhere

Comment: @AnuratChapanond, ($value)->create($post_type) is a custom method which I am using in my own class file.

Comment: @all, can I get any significant performance difference between these two?

Comment: @ProvatDas I was answering to NigelRen about the code not being a full replacement.

Comment: your code is unlikely computing extensive in the first place, so the performance difference would be negligible